# My request is retriving the data twice

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am experiencing issues with my query, it is retrieving all the objects twice (except the last one) I have been spending the last two days trying to sort it out with no result, so I thought that I could ask here. Thank you in advanced.

PS:

I've made a progress, the error comes from the query if I execute it on PHPMYADMIN the data is retrieved twice. (So can someone find an error in the query)

```
$token = ***

$userid = ***

$followingposts = $db->query('
    SELECT
        personal_posts.id, 
        personal_posts.body, 
        personal_posts.posted_at, 
        personal_posts.postimg, 
        personal_posts.likes, 
        users.`username`
    FROM users, personal_posts, followers
    WHERE (
        personal_posts.user_id = followers.user_id
        OR personal_posts.user_id = :userid
    )
    AND users.id = personal_posts.user_id
    AND follower_id = :userid
    ORDER BY personal_posts.posted_at DESC;
    ', array(':userid'=>$userid), array(':userid'=>$userid));
$response = "[";
foreach($followingposts as $post) {
    $response .= "{";
    $response .= '"PostId": '.$post['id'].',';
    $response .= '"PostBody": "'.$post['body'].'",';
    $response .= '"PostedBy": "'.$post['username'].'",';
    $response .= '"PostedAt": "'.$post['posted_at'].'",';
    $response .= '"PostImage": "'.$post['postimg'].'",';
    $response .= '"Likes": '.$post['likes'].'';
    $response .= "},";
}
$response = substr($response, 0, strlen($response)-1);
$response .= "]";
http_response_code(200);
echo $response;

    class DB {
        private $pdo;
        public function __construct() {
                $pdo = new PDO('****');
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->pdo = $pdo;
        }
        public function query($query, $params = array()) {
                $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute($params);
                if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
                $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $data;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: **Never roll your own JSON**. See [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Your arguments to `$db->query()` are wrong, the second argument shouldn't be `array(':userid'=>$userid)`.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: What is `$db`? I really hope it's not some custom PDO wrapper

Comment: That's not at all the function signature of `PDO::query()`, have you written a wrapper around PDO? [protip: don't] You're going to have to post the source of your wrapper class so we can see what it's actually doing. However, I suspect that it's your query that's getting duplicate results, you should try debugging that *outside* of PHP.

Comment: @chris85 why does it matter? OP's query is ANSI SQL

Comment: @KIKOSoftware What do you mean with shouldn't be, that it should not be repeted twice (If that is the case i've tryed it and i get the same results.

Comment: @Phil i don't think the JSON is the problem, i have another fuction that uses that same json roll.

Comment: Assuming it is the `PDO::query()` then you can easily find the correct argument in the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: @Itsmoloco it's not a problem *yet* but I guarantee it will be

Comment: It is @KIKOSoftware

Comment: @Phil Curious if there is an actual driver that works that way or if that is  homemade.

Comment: Just added the DB class from where i get $db->

Comment: OK, so it's not the original `PDO::query()`. Since your query only has two arguments you can just remove the third one. It is not the cause of your problem. I don't see why your rows should be duplicated.

Comment: Me neither @KikoSoftware but they are.

Comment: It's unlikely this code will work. PDO typically does not support named parameter re-use and you are using `:userid` twice. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-description) ~ *"You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on."*

Comment: @Phil by changing the first :userid to :useridB and then changing from , array(':userid'=>$userid), array(':userid'=>$userid) to  array(':userid'=>$userid, ':useridB'=>$userid) nothing happend.

Comment: I've made a progress, the error comes from the query if I execute it on PHPMYADMIN the data is retrieved twice. (PS. Thanks @Sammitch for recomending debuggin outside PHP). Can someone see any error in the query?

Comment: Well, you are creating a cartesian product by using multiple tables in the `FROM` clause. I'd use joins instead

Comment: @Phil what do you mean by using joins?

Comment: Regarding use of joins.. please see my "answer"  that displays these

Comment: Did not work @Used_By_Already

Comment: "did not work" ... did I suggest it would? you asked what a join was, so I demonstrated the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

(Partial answer at best.)

ANSI join syntax moves joining predicates out of the where clause and places them closer to the table references. This has been considered best practice in SQL queries for over 20 years. Time to stop using commas in the from clause and to be explicit about how the tables join together. E.g.

```
SELECT
    personal_posts.id, 
    personal_posts.body, 
    personal_posts.posted_at, 
    personal_posts.postimg, 
    personal_posts.likes, 
    users.`username`
FROM users
INNER JOIN personal_posts ON users.id = personal_posts.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN followers ON personal_posts.user_id = followers.user_id
WHERE personal_posts.user_id = :userid
ORDER BY personal_posts.posted_at DESC;
```

Note I'm not sure if the above query is an exact replacement

Comment: It did not work. (PS, it's valid (With valid I mean that the request executes, but inspite of that the repeating problem does not work) on PHPMYADMIN but on php it gives me Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in*****)